# ¿Es lo mismo agregar propiedades en gradle.properties y gradle-wrapper.properties?

Tags: android, gradle

Tengo un proyecto de Android Studio que tiene solamente al archivo `gradle-wrapper.properties` y cuando ejecuto el build me aparece un mensaje que tengo que agregar una propiedad nueva al `gradle.properties`, pero ese archivo no está en el proyecto.

El mensaje es el siguiente:

> For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle
>   daemon to more than 2048 MB. To do this set
>   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.

La pregunta es ¿Es lo mismo agergar la propiedad en `gradle-wrapper.properties`, en vez de  `gradle.properties` ? ¿Debería crear el archivo nuevo `gradle.properties` para agregar la propiedad  `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M`  dentro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO** es lo mismo.

Los que están en wrapper son configuraciones de las versiones locales de gradle y no se van a propagar fuera de tu ambiente (por ejemplo al resto de tu equipo si usan GIT).

El `gradle.properties` que está en el root de tu proyecto es el que rige como funciona tu proyecto, ese es el que deberías editar.